# how to construct dynamic url in objective c

Tags: string, url, dynamic, maps

i have url like this in objective c

NSString * currentUrl = [NSString stringWithFormat: @"https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/photo?maxwidth=400&userId=%@&key=key", userId];

so here user id is dynamically changes

not static

so i need complete url like this means output

https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/photo?maxwidth=400&userId=35&key=abc

but its not working i tried lot of ways can anybody help me please

Comment: please give me solution ASAP

Comment: need help form you devops